# How to edit a macro for F5 in Latex Suite

Tags: filetype-tex

I have an environment for Theorem (aliased to "thm")
When in VIM editor I write

"thm" followed by "F5"  I get:

```
\begin{thm}

\end{thm}<++>
```

Can I edit the macro so that I get instead:

```
\begin{thm}<++>

\end{thm}<++>
```

It is the case in many theorems where we want to add the name of the theorem.
For example: Roll's theorem....

with the cursor at the beginning?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: This is probably a « snippet », so answers will need to figure out how latex suite is handling those

Comment: Can you tell us which plugins you have installed? Especially which LatexSuite do you have, because duckduckgo returns several results.

Comment: @statox: I am not sure how to answer your question. I downloaded Tex-Suite. Installed under the directory .vim in my home directory. It has a directory called ftplugin, this has  a directory called latex-suite,  This directory has 32 files and directories. One of them is "envmacros.vim" . I believe that file is the one I need to edit.

Comment: @HermanJaramillo My question was about where you downloaded TexSuite because there are several plugins which provide Tex features and to be able to help you we need to know which one exactly you are using.

Comment: @statox: To be frank, I do not remember. Tomorrow I will download a new tex-suite so that I know how to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my question.
In the "envmacros.vim" file (under ~/.vim/ftplugin/latex-suite) I defined:

```
let g:Tex_Env_thm = "\\begin{thm}[<++>]\<CR><++>\<CR>\\end{thm}<++>"
```

then, when I type 
thm
and push < F5> I get:

```
\begin{thm}[]
    <++>
\end{thm}<++>
```

The cursor located inside the square brackets [].  If I do not want to name the theorem, I move with ctrl-j  to the inside, and another ctrl-j to exit