# What is `<++>`?

Tags: filetype-tex

In [the example in this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/25744/how-to-edit-a-macro-for-f5-in-latex-suite), and in the [latex-suite documentation](https://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/altkey-mappings.html), what is `<++>`?

Comment: I believe those are placeholders: https://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/latex-macros.html#place-holders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a **placeholder**.

They are really helpful, if you want to write some macros or some other things too :)